# Compiling dependent .c and .cu files with nvcc

Tags: c, cuda, linker, nvcc

I'd like to have a few host helper functions written in regular old C to be include'd in a .cu file which runs some of that host code and also defines and calls kernel functions. I have no knowledge of makefiles and don't have a good feel for multi-file projects in general, and can't understand why the following works with a .c extension but fails with a .cu extension.

A.h

```
void sayhello();
```

A.c:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void sayhello() {
    printf("Hello from A\n");
}
```

B.c:

```
#include "A.h"
int main(int argc, char * argv) {
    sayhello();
    return 0;
}
```

B.cu

```
#include "A.h"
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    sayhello();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile A.c everything works fine:

```
$ nvcc -arch compute_30 -code sm_30 -o test B.c A.c  
$ ./test  
Hello from A
```

But when trying to compile B.cu the linker can't find sayhello()

```
$ nvcc -o test B.cu A.c  
/tmp/tmpxft_000017bb_00000000-16_B.o: In function 'main':
tmpxft_000017bb_00000000-4_B.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to 'sayhello()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why isn't it finding sayhello(), what's the difference between these compilations, and is there a solution to compiling code of this structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA uses a C++ compiler to compile `.cu` files. Therefore, it expects that all functions referenced in `.cu` files have C++ linkage unless explicitly instructed otherwise. And in your case, you must explicitly instruct the C++ compiler otherwise.

You should find that modifying your code like this:

```
extern "C" { 
#include "A.h"
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    sayhello();
    return 0;
}
```

will fix the problem as it will instruct the compiler to expect C linkage for your C functions, not C++ linkage.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use `__host__ __device__` decoration on the sayhello function.

Also, include cuda_runtime.h in A.h

Comment: neither of these suggestions are correct or needed.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide the correct solution then.

Comment: I believe the answer provided by @talonmies is correct and sufficient.